# Regex to exclude quoted strings

Tags: regex, vbscript

I know that there are tons of similar question; I read hundreds, but...for my litlle knowledge of English and my even lower knowledge of Regex, I'am still in the fog.
I need to elaborate a quite large text file which includes paragraphs in two formats: enclosed in quotes or not; in both cases paragraphs could have one or more Carriage Return. I have to process only the lines enclosed in quotes. So: "This is \r a phrase" must be processed (actually I have to replace the \r with ad dummy character like '#'), while 'This is \r a comment' must be excluded.
I tried this pattern: "[\s\S(\r)]+"
This correctly selects only the enclosed paragraphs, but the regex debugger does not report the \r group to be replaced.

Comment: You can first match from an opening till closing quote, and over that match replace the carriage returns.

Comment: Right, it's what I did (match anything inside quotes) but I do not  get any matching group for \r so I do know how to replace them. Possibly I do not know or understand your 'and over that match replace...'. Would you give me an example?

Answer (score -2):

Try this pattern: "[\s\S]*(\r)[\s\S]*"

You need to escape the \ character, since \r means something specific with RegEx.

Comment: Sorry but your pattern does not match any of these phrases;   "RegExr was created by gskinner.com, and is proudly hosted by Media Temple.
Explore results with the Tools below. Replace & List output custom results" 
Explain describes your expression 
in plain English.